# VS2019 C++ Console App - Debugger Will Not Accept Command Arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I am totally at a loss with this!  I am working on a C++ Console project and trying to pass a text "Command File" (in same Debug file location) to the debugger via the Command Arguments window.  The console project compiles fine and will execute the following no problems when manually typed into the console itself:

"COMMAND FILE = PLOT.CON"

I have tried other commands with and without quotes and nothing works.  I have set the command line in the property pages:[image: Property Pages]

I just get the following error when I run the debugger:

**Undefined command line parameter (C)**

Any help please?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling and running in Debug?  It's easy, with Visual Studio, for the Properties window to get out of sync with your active configuration.  If in doubt set the "Configuration" to "Active" or "All."

Failing that, could you post the code you use to parse the command line and print the error message?

Comment: Thank you ! This was the answer for me, and it's not the first time this bites me.

Answer (score 1):

I may have part of your answer. I've been learning C++ and writing command-line progs to do so. I discovered some time ago that the facility for providing command-line args when debugging does not appear to work. Specifically, the right stuff doesn't end up in argc and argv[]. I also found that the current directory for the running debug executable is not where the executable happens to be. I wrote a function called setupArgs to fix the problem. It looks like this:

void setupArgs(int argc, char **argv)
{
    argcc = argc;
    
    for (int x = 0; x

Elsewhere in the code, argcc is defined as an int and argvv is defined as a std::vector<std::string>.

As you can see, it copies the usual stuff from argc and argv[] into new variables which the main program then analyzes instead. To debug, you uncomment the stuff at the bottom to feed in fake args and change the working dir. HTH,

Lars

Answer (score 0):

Hi Charles/EvilTeach and thanks for your answers.  The project I am working on contains a great deal of legacy code and that, coupled with the issues I have surrounding VS2019 set up and various libraries etc mean that it is not really fair for me to continue with this post: I need to go back and look at a great many things.  Thanks for your replies but I don't think it's fair to anybody to persist with this issue without a lot more work on my part to make things clearer.  I wish to draw this to a close for now! Cheers Paul